# Creating new project with asp.net Identity and Database First

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity, ef-database-first

Creating new project with database first using model.emdx . 
I want to use identity for this project. I want to keep files like account controller and other auto generated identity files.
How do i make it database first. what changes are required?

Comment: Something like that? https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Comment: @Marco Yes! but the link you shared has nothing about identity. which i want to use.

Comment: Identity comes with it's own classes like AspNetUsers, wouldn't generating emdx model duplicate these classes? is there any change required or should i just script the identity tables and change web.config? @PawełHemperek

Comment: Scripting database should be enough. You can create those identity classes by yourself.